# two right joins selects in one query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to join two tables, and each must have a common relationship.

One table is for "purchases" and another for "payments", both are directly related to the "customers" table.

I tried that, but it is not working.

```
SELECT c.id AS idclient, c.name AS nameclient, p.id AS idpayment, cp.id AS idpurchases 
            FROM clients AS c
                RIGHT JOIN payments AS p ON c.id = p.client
                RIGHT JOIN purchases AS cp ON c.id = cp.client
```

The tables have different structures and other fields that are not currently needed. The fields are basically the ones that are in the select.

**Expected outcome:**

When a customer is NOT listed in the "purchases" or "payments" tables, it should not be listed, with the exception of a Boolean clause in the "purchases" table (company business rule).

```
idclient | nameclient | idpurchases | idpayment

109      | John       | 3           | NULL
27       | Code       | 1           | 1
302      | Woen       | 4           | NULL
NULL     | NULL       | 2           | NULL
```

Comment: Provide (simplified - remove excess columns/attributes) table structures (CREATE TABLE scripts), some sample data (INSERT INTO scripts) and desired result for shown sample data. And specify MySQL version - it may be important.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you need RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN? I suppose record in the clients table always exists comparing to payments and purchases.
2. For instance if you have 2 payments and 2 ppurchases for a certain client you'll get 4 rows with the same client_id and all combinations of idpayment and idpurchases (2x2). Do you really need such a result?

Comment: "I need to join two tables".  Why does your query reference three tables, then?

Comment: right, I updated the expected result, sorry for that

Comment: Please see my answer and consider whether this is really the result you are after. Then, what do you mean with "the exception of a Boolean clause in the purchases table"? And isn't there anything to relate a payment to a purchase? Can a payment even exist without a purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join the three tables, but only show clients that have an entry in at least one of the tables `payments` and `purchases`. So outer join these tables and use a where clause to ensure at least one of them has a match.

```
SELECT c.id AS idclient, c.name AS nameclient, p.id AS idpayment, cp.id AS idpurchases 
FROM clients AS c
LEFT JOIN payments AS p ON p.client = c.id
LEFT JOIN purchases AS cp ON cp.client = c.id
WHERE (p.client IS NOT NULL OR cp.client IS NOT NULL);
```

This is a strange query, however, because the table design suggests there can be multiple payments and multiple purchases per client, but your query combines each payment with each purchase a client made. Aren't they somehow related? Would a client make a payment without having purchased anything? What I am saying is, while you asked for this query, you may really want a completely different one.

Comment: Exactly. There may be payments recorded without a purchase for integrity to the financial report. Since customers can be excluded due to inactivity, as there are thousands and they slow down the system for queries.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me with the solution.
SELECT ... | FROM purchases AS cp | LEFT JOIN payments ... | JOIN clients ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as i see you need `LEFT JOIN`.

 Meaning you have clients with no purchases and no payments.

Or the client is doing the purchase but still didn't pay

There are no purchase and no payments with out an client !

```
SELECT c.id AS idclient, c.name AS nameclient,
       p.id AS idpayment,
       cp.id AS idpurchases 
FROM clients AS c
LEFT JOIN payments AS p ON c.id = p.client
LEFT JOIN purchases AS cp ON c.id = cp.client
```

Possible output
`[idclient,name, idpay,idPur]`

 `[1,A,2,3]` - ok

 `[2,B,null,4]` - no payment :ok

 `[3,C,null,null]` - no purchase and no payment : ok

or 
use `JOIN(inner)` to get without null `[1,A,2,3]`

```
SELECT c.id AS idclient, c.name AS nameclient,
       p.id AS idpayment,
       cp.id AS idpurchases 
FROM purchases AS cp
//left if wanted all record
//inner : now only all columns populated 
JOIN payments AS p ON cp.client = p.client
JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = cp.client
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I need just the opposite. When there is **NO** customer in the purchases or payments table, it should not be listed.

Comment: fine, if the logic is to have `purchases` and `payments` populated with out `customer`. `LEFT JOIN` work fine, just switch tables. Update the answer

Comment: I don't use LEFT JOIN because I don't need to list customers who don't have purchases or payments. Only JOIN worked for me.

Comment: Yes. Basically just `join` means `inner`(only equality) and matches only `not null` on criteria

Comment: Thanks! @Traian GEICU